# django pytest / update delete view testing

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest

I'm working on pytest testing for my 1st django app, kind of cookery book.

I have problems with edit/delete view tests.

For example, i have a test for testing add recipe view.

Here is recipe model:

```
    class Recipe(models.Model):
        """Instructions how to prepare a single dish."""
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        cooking_time = models.IntegerField(help_text='in minutes', validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5000)])
        difficulty_level = models.IntegerField(choices=DIFFICULTY_LEVELS, default=1)
        description = models.TextField()
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        cuisine = models.ForeignKey('Cuisine', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='IngredientRecipe')
        meal_plan = models.ManyToManyField('MealPlan', through='RecipeMealPlan')
```

here is it's fixture:

```
    @pytest.fixture()
    def example_recipe():
        rec = Recipe.objects.create(title='rec', cooking_time=10, difficulty_level=2, description='bla, bla, bla')
        return rec
```

And tests which works fine:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_add_recipe(client, example_recipe):
    dct = {
        'title': 'rec',
        'cooking_time': 10,
        'difficulty_level': 2,
        'description': 'bla, bla, bla'
    }
    url = reverse('add-recipe')
    response = client.post(url, dct)
    assert response.status_code == 302
    assert Recipe.objects.get(**dct)




@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_add_recipe2(client):
    url = reverse('add-recipe')
    response = client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 302
```

Now I'm trying to write test for recipe update/delete views.

My recipe update test currently looks like this:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_ingredient_update_view(client, example_ingredient):
    url = reverse('update-ingredient', kwargs={'id': example_ingredient.id})
    response = client.get(url)
    assert Ingredient.objects.save(
        name='cos',
        nutrient=2,
        glycemic_index=2
    )
```

I know its wrong but i face problems to make it work. Same with delete view.

Could someone take a look on above and give me some advice?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the error you get? Apart from that - `Ingredient.objects.save` won't work, a manager doesn't have saving functionality. What is the last assert line supposed to test?

Comment: Here is how i changed it:

Comment: i will add it as question answer

Answer (score 0):

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_ingredient_update_view(client, example_ingredient):
    url = reverse('update-ingredient', kwargs={'pk': example_ingredient.pk})
    response = client.get(url)
    obj = Ingredient.objects.get(example_ingredient.pk)
    obj.name = 'else'
    obj.save()
    assert response.status_code == 302
```

current error is:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).